# How to get a password from Spring Security?

Tags: spring, security, passwords

I use LDAP for authentication in my application.
(class=org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider)

I need get a login and password inside app and I try this code:

```
UserDetails user = (UserDetails)  
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

request.setUser("aartemenko");
request.clearPeriod();
logger.debug("LOGIN: {} PASSWORD{}", user.getUsername(), user.getPassword().to_string);
```

But the password like this **{MD5}7XEGS32KbJ0bpCMj9pNdqg==**
How do i get unhashed password?

Comment: That is a one way hash. You can't get the clear text password from it.

Comment: **It should never be possible be get a password**.

Comment: I guess the question is, why do you need it?

Comment: Just try http://www.openwall.com/john and let it rip for a few months.

Comment: The Intention for Hashing is to hide the original password string.
Not a good idea.

Comment: I need use same password for external service.